# Go-Gorm: will the foreignkey be auto-populated when I set an object?

Tags: go, go-gorm

In the documentation we have this example:

```
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name string
}

// `Profile` belongs to `User`, `UserID` is the foreign key
type Profile struct {
  gorm.Model
  UserID int
  User   User
  Name   string
}
```

If I do something like `profile.User = &user`, will that automatically populate the `UserID` field? Is it recommended to set both? Like:

```
profile.User = &user
profile.UserID = &user.ID
```

Or is that pointless? Furthermore, could I alternatively just set the `UserID` field and ignore the `User` field entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I do something like `profile.User = &user`, will that automatically populate the UserID field?

Just writing `profile.User = &user` will not populate the `UserID` field. Once you add the `profile` to the database. gorm will automatically populate the foreign key.

> Is it recommended to set both?

Nope. In fact, you should *not* set the `UserID` yourself. This answers the last question as well.

Comment: thanks, this is helpful but could you go into why the foreignKey should not be set manually? I've been doing this in situations where I don't want to query the db for the whole object beforehand.

Comment: but how to get the `UserID` without querying the db? Can I describe a scenario? I am not sure I follow

Comment: if it's in the case of a REST API route, we will already have the UserID because of some route like /users/:id. In this case I could just set the `UserID` to `:id`. There isn't a problem with this right?

Comment: Sorry for the typo in the Q? But you seem to have understood what I meant "Can **you** describe a scenario?".. Anyways, it seems that your model is different from the one you presented in the question. `gorm.Model` contains an `ID` which is an auto incremented `primary_key`. Unless you query the last inserted ID, you can't predict the next key. Even that's not enough if data is being deleted since it will not use the same primary key twice. If that is indeed the case, then yes, there is no problem with setting the `UserID` the way you described.